# Слова "следовательно" и "значит" обособляются по-разному?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

*Тучи собираются, **значит** будет дождь.

Ты сердишься, **значит** ты не прав.

Времени осталось мало, **а значит** нужно торопиться.

Времени осталось мало,  **следовательно**, нужно торопиться.*

Читая правила и примеры, я так и не могу до конца понять: **как же отделять запятыми данные водные слова?**
Многие примеры абсолютно похожи по смыслу, но выделены запятыми по-разному. Особенно смущают союзы **и**, **а** перед этими вводными словами. Так может, в спорных ситуациях запятые ставить факультативно, как рука возьмет? Так же как это делали классики, примеры которых, как правило, приводятся во многих справочниках?
По крайней мере, я так думаю. Может, я и не прав?

Answer (score 3):

Пунктуация при слове значит вызывает у пишущих многочисленные затруднения. Если попытаться суммировать рекомендации словарей и справочных пособий по правописанию, можно сделать следующие выводы.

Значит  в предложении может выступать как связка, союз, вводное слово, а также употребляться в значении сказуемого. Если значит  употребляется как связка (то же, что «это, есть») и присоединяет сказуемое к подлежащему, перед ним ставится тире: Понять человека – значит простить. Ждать официального разрешения – значит потерять время.

Союз значит (то же, что «и поэтому, следовательно») соединяет простые предложения в составе сложного. Запятая ставится перед союзом: Тучи собираются, значит будет дождь. Ты сердишься, значит ты не прав.

В качестве вводного слово значит указывает на связь мыслей, последовательность их изложения; вводное слово значит, выделяемое с двух сторон запятыми, можно заменить на «стало быть, выходит»: Село, значит, наше – Радово, // Дворов, почитай, два ста. // Тому, кто его оглядывал, // Приятственны наши места (С. Есенин, Анна Снегина). Собираешься, значит, уезжать? Ты, значит, думаешь иначе?  Слово значит, расположенное в начале предложения, также рассматривается как вводное и выделяется запятой: Ты сердишься... Значит, ты не прав.

Наконец, слово значит, выступающее в  значении сказуемого, не требует постановки знаков препинания: Что все это значит?

Таковы рекомендации справочников. Однако практика письма показывает, что слово значит обычно выделяется знаками препинания почти во всех своих синтаксических функциях (кроме функции сказуемого). Кроме того, во многих случаях возможны варианты пунктуации в одном и том же предложении. Ср. одинаково возможные: Ревнует, значит (=и следовательно) любит; Ревнует – значит (=это) любит. В спорных случаях окончательное решение о расстановке знаков препинания принимает автор текста. (Грамота.ру)

> Вводные слова и сочетания могут отделяться или не отделяться запятой от предшествующего сочинительного союза в зависимости от контекста.

Запятая после союза ставится, если вводное слово можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры.

> ..Перед уходом я достал из-под стекла список и предельным нажимом вымарал слово «Волобуй» своей радужной ручкой. Я решился на это потому, что оно лохматилось бумажными ворсинками ***и, значит,*** его уже царапали до меня когтем…

Если же изъятие вводного слова невозможно (т. е. союз включается во вводную конструкцию, образуя с ней единое сочетание), то запятая после союза не ставится (обычно это бывает при союзе а).

...Случайно появляется газ или нет, связан ли он с циклонами, ***а значит,*** можно ли по этому признаку прогнозировать – вопрос требует выяснения

Не отделяются запятой вводные слова от союзов, стоящих в начале предложения:

> И действительно, он скоро уехал;
>
> ***А между прочим,*** магазин уже был закрыт;
>
> ***И в самом деле,*** послышались голоса внизу (Ч.); И пожалуй, он правильно поступил.
> СЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО, вводное слово и союз

1. Вводное слово. Указывает на связь мыслей, последовательность их изложения; то же, что «стало быть». Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми. Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах см. в Приложении 2.

Чтобы решить эту задачу, нужно сперва узнать, кто из них больше всех взнес, а для этого нужно все три числа повычитать одно из другого, и получим, следовательно, что третий купец взнес больше всех… А. Чехов, Каникулярные работы институтки Наденьки N.

2. Союз. То же, что «и поэтому, а значит». Синтаксические конструкции с союзом «следовательно» выделяются знаками препинания, обычно запятыми.

Нужно было видеть и слышать, как он умел отделать, иногда не щадя себя, следовательно с риском, почти с геройством, кого-нибудь из своих покровителей, уже донельзя его разбесившего. Ф. Достоевский, Ползунков. Я – русский человек, следовательно имею право это сказать. С. Надсон, Дневники.

Справочник по пунктуации. Свинцов Виктор Викторович, Пахомов Владимир Маркович, Филатова Ирина Витальевна

См. Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь Д. Э. Полный академический справочник.

Comment: Серж, буду очень благодарен за источник, где разбирается эта — *Тучи собираются, значит будет дождь* — и подобные фразы. Хочу понять получше все такие случаи, где не нужна запятая.

Comment: @Артем Лугавой, так я же указал источники.

Comment: ЛугАвой? Ну ладно)) А именно эта фраза из какого из них?

Comment: @Артем Луговой, пожалуйста. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Значит, присоединительные отношения это. :)

Comment: Запомнил, наконец, сайт, на котором всё это, а то попадал туда всегда по ссылкам. А теперь смотрю — чёткий сайт! 

Comment: Если забудете: Напишите в Яндекс "Полный академический справочник" и попадете на этот сайт. В поисковике обычно первый.

Comment: Спасибо! Проверил — и в Гугле тоже первый. ;) Привык просто к нему.

Comment: Ну, главное - вам удобно.

Answer (score 3):

Предложения с вводными словами можно оформить различным образом, но при этом желательно понимать грамматическую функцию вводного слова и избегать скопления запятых.

Следует учитывать, что вводные слова дополнительно определяют семантику отношений  между простыми предложениями в составе сложного, поэтому допускается использовать запятые вместо тире.

ПРИМЕР РЕШЕНИЯ

Тучи собираются, а значит, будет дождь. Тучи собираются - значит, будет дождь.

Ты сердишься, а значит, ты не прав. Ты сердишься - значит, ты не прав.

Примечание

1) Ты сердишься, значит, ты не прав. Вариант допустимый, но здесь много запятых, становится неясной структура небольшого по объему предложения предложения.

2) Ты сердишься, значит ты не прав. Вводные слова должны обособляться. Они не обособляются в двух случаях: а) в качестве сказуемого; б) в качестве связки между подлежащим и именным сказуемым.

ПОЯСНЕНИЯ

Вводные слова могут быть а) аналогами союзов или б) использоваться совместно  с союзами  в качестве дополнительных структурных элементов, например:

1) Вводное слово в качестве союза (союз ПРАВДА=НО): Я хочу пригласить друга на праздник, правда, я не уверен, сможет ли он прийти

2) Вводное слово  в качестве структурного элемента используется совместно  с союзом: Наверное, он дома, потому что в окнах горит свет.

3) Слово ЗНАЧИТ (СЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО, А ЗНАЧИТ, А СЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО) может выступать в роли союза в БСП или входить в состав  союза  ЕСЛИ…ЗНАЧИТ,  РАЗ…ЗНАЧИТ в СПП:

Послал он мне крест – значит, меня он любит (БСП).
Раз вы читаете это мое письмецо, значит, я вас уже покинул (СПП).

4) Слово ЗНАЧИТ в качестве структурного элемента может использоваться в предложении с однородными членами: Это вполне естественно, а значит, и справедливо.

ВЫВОД

1) При обособлении вводных слов "значит, следовательно" нет четко обозначенной грамматики, следствием чего и являются  "многочисленные затруднения" при решении подобных задач.

2) Вводные слова  могут использоваться **в качестве союзов или входить в состав двухместного союза,** выражая  дополнительные смысловые отношения между простыми предложениями или однородными членами. В этом случае они обособляются.

3) Вводные слова "значит и следовательно" обособляются по одним правилам, но слово "значит" может выполнять другие функции (сказуемое, связка).

Comment: Вера, а чем вам не нравится этот вариант: Тучи собираются, а значит, будет дождь? Две запятые при вводным слове - это много? Тогда получается вводные слова отделятся тире и запятой. И не совсем понятно, для чего в данном предложении помимо запятой тире.

Comment: "Тучи собираются, а значит, будет дождь" - мне нравится, так как союз А дополнительно обозначает границу между предложениями. Тире ставится как вариант, если хотите обозначить паузу, например: "Целый обоз снарядился с нами ― значит, в разведки поехали". Но тире чаще ставится в распространенных предложениях.

Comment: Знаете, Вера, здесь скорее всего причинно-следственные отношения,тогда тире оправдано.

Comment: Здесь во всех случаях причинно-следственные отношения. Можно так сказать: Тучи собираются - будет дождь. Здесь нужно обязательное тире, отношения выражены только интонацией. Если используем вводное слово, то можно обойтись запятой, так как вводное слово выражает причинно-следственные отношения, а можно одновременно использовать оба средства - тире  и вводное слово (на усмотрение автора).

Comment: " Словарь вводных слов " О.А. Остроумова, О.Д. Фрамполь.   
 
2. Невводное, употребляется внутри простого предложения между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными инфинитивами, в качестве связки при сказуемом, не обособляется: А понять человека - значит уже сочувствовать ему (В.Шукшин); 
3. Невводное, употребляется в функции союза (= следовательно), соединяет части сложносочиненного предложения или однородные члены предложения, не обособляется: Тучи собираются, значит будет дождь; Ты сердишься, значит ты не прав; Все идут в эту сторону, значит там и клюква растет (М.Пришвин).

Comment: Угрюм, в функции союза запятая вариативна.

Comment: Советую почитать этот словарь. Он еще раз доказывает факультативность знаков препинания  у различных авторов.  Фрамполь О.А. Остроумова О.Д.  «Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений» состоит из собственно вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений, а также слов и сочетаний, которые часто принимают за вводные (всего более 1400 лексических единиц).

Назначение словаря – помочь решить, может ли слово, которое пишущий хочет обособить запятыми и тем самым оформить как вводное, являться таковым в принципе, а также является ли это слово в данном контексте вводным или не является.

Comment: Вводные слова  могут выполнять функцию  присоединительного союза и не обособляться, например: "Княжна, вероятно допив уж последний стакан, прохаживалась задумчиво у колодца". Но здесь вводное слово относится к обособленному обороту. В нашем же  случае  вводное слово выражает смысловые отношения между простыми предложениями в составе сложного предложения, поэтому его нежелательно присоединять ко второму предложению. ГРАММАТИЧЕСКОЕ РЕШЕНИЕ  должно быть четким: вводное слово может быть союзным средством, оставаясь при этом вводным словом, а пунктуация должна просто СООТВЕТСТВОВАТЬ грамматике.

Comment: Автор должен "выбирать"  разрешенную грамматику и называть (определять, понимать)  эту грамматику, а знаки препинания должны соответствовать грамматике. Если этого не будет,  то Вы так и останетесь при своем мнении: "Читая правила и примеры, я так и не могу до конца понять..." Никакой словарь вводных слов не поможет. Впрочем, это мое личное мнение, общепринятым является озвученная Сержем фраза: "в функции союза запятая вариативна".

Comment: Согласен с вами, Вера. Автор не только должен слепо следовать правилам, но и иметь чувство грамматики, уметь разбираться в структуре предложения. Только тогда, опираясь на правила, он сумеет правильно расставить знаки препинания.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за поддержку. а то со мной  редко кто соглашается.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что давно не было реформы пунктуации. Согласно Розенталю и, соответственно, правилам пунктуации, которые он сформулировал, "значит" и "следовательно" не бывают союзами. На стыке частей предложения они всегда вводные слова и выделяются запятыми.

Согласно современным ученым, в этой позиции "значит" и "следовательно" - союзы и запятыми не выделяются. Эта рекомендация отражена в "Полном академическом справочнике пунктуации". Но работники СМИ и школьные учителя пользуются учебниками Розенталя. Отсюда и разнобой.

Пишите как хотите:

*Времени осталось мало, следовательно, нужно торопиться* (по Розенталю).

*Времени осталось мало, следовательно нужно торопиться* (по ПАС).

Comment: Я бы пожелала современным ученым больше истинной  учености (боюсь, что Ломоносовых среди них немного). У нас правописание и грамматика, по-видимому, разные ведомства, а россиянам приходится писать как в 17 веке - кому как нравится.

Comment: Вот, к примеру, предложения:Я хочу пригласить друга на праздник, правда, я не уверен, сможет ли он прийти. Наверное, он дома, потому что в окнах горит свет". Вводное слово используется как СТРУКТУРНЫЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ,  определяющий отношения в БСП, и нет никакой необходимости превращать его в союз. Следует только  "набраться побольше учености" и РАЗРЕШИТЬ вводным словам использоваться совместно с союзами или без них, не меняя свой статус вводного слова.

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее всего будет написать: "Ты сердишься: ты не прав" но по смыслу больше подойдёт "Ты сердишься — ты не прав"  http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185